# matplotlib - positioning xlabel/ylabel when using multi axes (hist + scatter)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to create a scatter plot bounded by histograms of the data to the left and bottom of the scatter plot. I have been following this example (where the plot is bounded to the top and right):
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html

I have successfully changed the margins and sizes to get the histograms where I want them, but I'm not sure how to tell mpl where to put the xlabel and ylabel. For example, using (where now axHistx and axHisty are modified to be left of/below the scatter):

```
axScatter = axes(scat_area)
axHistx = axes(hist_area_x)
axHisty = axes(hist_area_y)
...
xlabel('this is the x axis')
ylabel('this is the y axis')
```

Will place the xlabel below the histogram on the left (`axHisty`). I want it centered under the histogram on the bottom. I cannot use `axHistx.xlabel()` since axes objects do not have that attribute. (I am happy with where the ylabel has eneded up, though)

[image: current output]

Comment: So I may have answered it, though I'm not sure if it's really The Right Way: `sca(axHistx); xlabel()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
axHisty.set_xlabel("this is the x axis")
```

Comment: or maybe 'axHistx' is the right one, but anyway you get the point.  set_xlabel() should make it centered by default.